# When is $L^\infty(E)$ separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I wonder how to exhibit a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ for which $L^\infty(E)$ is separable. It's clear that $L^\infty(E)$ is not separable if $E$ contains any nondegenerate interval(to be honest i am still a little confused about the result ). Any idea?

Comment: *Any* measurable set? Finite sets work; in this case $L^\infty$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Yet already countable sets do not work, for then you have something isomorphic to $\ell^\infty$, and $\ell^\infty$ contains an uncountable discrete set. For an example, define the function $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell^\infty,f(A)_n=1$ if $n \in A$, $0$ otherwise; then the image of $f$ is an uncountable discrete subset of $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @Ian That works with the counting measure, but using Lebesgue measure (which I think was the OP's intent) gives zero-norm for all elements.

Comment: Er, yes, sorry, my mistake. I was thinking about the resulting Hausdorff measure for some reason...

Comment: As for clarifying your confusion about the case of an interval, say $[a,b]$, you can consider the functions $f_y=\chi_{[a,y]}$ where $y$ ranges over $[a,b]$ and observe that they form an uncountable discrete set. As for forcing it to be separable...that seems tough when the underlying space is $\mathbb{R}$. I'm not so sure an example even exists.

Comment: Please do disregard my first comment, it does not really apply to your context.

Comment: Actually i haven't thought of the counting measure at first, hah

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the measure you're using has to  be Lebesgue measure, then you're out of luck. The only measurable sets $E$ for which $L^\infty(E)$ is separable are the sets of measure zero, for which $L^\infty(E)$ is the zero vector space.

If you allow other measures, then you could let $E$ be a finite set, with some measure that gives each point in $E$ a positive measure.  Then $L^\infty(E)$ is finite-dimensional and thus separable.  But this is essentially all you can do.

Here's a proof for the case of Lebesgue measure; it can be adapted to other situations. If $E$ has positive measure, it can be partitioned into a countable infinity of measurable subsets $A_0,A_1,\dots$ that all have positive measure.  To each subset $X$ of $\mathbb N$, associate the function $f_X$ that sends all points from $A_n$ to $1$ if $n\in X$ and  to $0$ otherwise.  Each of these functions $f_X$ is in $L^\infty(E)$, and the $L^\infty$ distance between any two of them is $1$. So we have uncountably many elements of $L^\infty(E)$, all a distance $1$ from each  other.  That prevents separability, since no point can be closer than a distance $\frac12$to more than one of these points $f_X$.

Comment: Any set of measure zero makes $L^\infty(E)$ separable?

Comment: @S.Bryant Any set of measure zero makes $L^\infty(E)$ zero (and therefore separable). Remember that, in defining $L^\infty$, one identifies any two functions that differ only on a set of measure zero.  So, if $E$ has measure zero, all the functions will be identified.

Comment: ok I think I get it~thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Hi Andreas, do we need this countable infinity of measurable subsets to be almost disjoint?

Comment: @Flashhh In my answer, those sets were disjoint (I wrote "partitioned"), but almost disjointness (modulo measure zero sets) would suffice.  All I really used about the $A_n$'s is that they easily generate uncountably many measurable sets no two of which differ by only a measure-zero set.